# Run-time error 1004 while setting ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make an array of ranges, but I'm getting "application-defined or object-defined error". The error is appearing on the line with `Set Rng`. The format *should* be fine, even if the line is somewhat long. I've specified the sheet I'm trying to get the ranges from, and the sub is currently in Module 1. It *could* just be a typo error somewhere, but after having re-checked the line six times I'd be disappointed if that was it.

```
Sub TableRange(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim Rng As Range
   Dim Area As Range
   Set Rng = Worksheets("Tables").Range("A3:D23,A28:C39,A44:E61,A66:C102,A107:E121,A126:C135,A140:C149,A153:C162,A167:C192,A197:F215,A220:C269,A274:D282,A287:D295,A300:D304")
   Set Rng = Union(Rng, Worksheets("Tables").Range("A309:C358,A363:C389,A394:C412,A417:C437,A442:C462,A467:D475,A480:D487,A492:C531,A536:D544,A549:D557,A562:C574,A579:D598,A603:D622"))

   For Each Area In Rng.Areas
      If Not Intersect(Target, Worksheets("Tables").Range(Area)) Is Nothing Then
         'do stuff
      End If
   Next Area
End Sub
```

If there is anything else I should mention or that I can do to improve my question, let me know and I'll edit my post accordingly.

---

**Update**: Range array has been fixed, thanks to @user3964075, but now I seem to be stuck with the same error on `If Not Intersect - Is Nothing Then`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is fine, but string constant exceeds maximum length (255 chars) allowed for `Range` property. You can easily fix it with:

```
Set Rng = Worksheets("Tables").Range("A3:D23,A28:C39,A44:E61,A66:C102,A107:E121,A126:C135,A140:C149,A153:C162,A167:C192,A197:F215,A220:C269,A274:D282,A287:D295,A300:D304")
Set Rng = Union(Rng, Worksheets("Tables").Range("A309:C358,A363:C389,A394:C412,A417:C437,A442:C462,A467:D475,A480:D487,A492:C531,A536:D544,A549:D557,A562:C574,A579:D598,A603:D622"))
```

Maybe consider using Named Range instead of this long list.

**EDIT:** To fix the second problem, change it to:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Area) Is Nothing Then
     'do stuff
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! That definitely worked for me. Although now I'm getting the same error on `If Not Intersect - Is Nothing Then`, and I'm not sure what to do with it since the length shouldn't be an issue anymore.

Comment: @Looker answer updated with fix for the second problem

Comment: Tested with a `MsgBox`, worked beautifully. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are not dealing with the [Range.Areas property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196243.aspx) properly. Try a loop through the index.

```
dim a as long
For a =1 to Rng.Areas.count
   If Not Intersect(Target, Rng.Areas(a)) Is Nothing Then
      'do stuff
   End If
Next a
```

Comment: Second time I'm making you come and fix my indexing issues :p Unfortunately when I tried to replace the 'do stuff' with `MsgBox Rng.Areas(a)` I got a type mismatch on that line. (I also had to remove the 'Each' for the loop to start)

Comment: `Rng.Areas(a)` is a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx). If you want to see a string like the address displayed in a msgbox then `MsgBox Rng.Areas(a).address`.

Comment: Sorry about the `each`. I just typed that out from your sample and neglected to erase the `Each` when I overtyped.

Comment: Don't worry about it, just figured it was worth pointing out so you could edit your answer if you wanted. Thank you for your time and explanations, what you suggested works as well.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the `Set Rng` Line and had the same error.
When I removed one range, i.e. `A28:C39` it works. It does not matter which Range will be removed.
Maybe there is a maximum of Ranges?

Try:

```
Set Rng = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A3:D23,A44:E61,A66:C102,A107:E121,A126:C135,A140:C149,A153:C162,A167:C192,A197:F215,A220:C269,A274:D282,A287:D295,A300:D304,A309:C358,A363:C389,A394:C412,A417:C437,A442:C462,A467:D475,A480:D487,A492:C531,A536:D544,A549:D557,A562:C574,A579:D598,A603:D622")
```